# adjusting the size of objects to the size of the screen

Tags: android, xml

I'm beginning to write the application in the android studio and i have a question? What is the best way on scale  objects to screen size.  The point is that when i run my aplication on phone with smaller screen objects shouldn't be cut off or overlap on them self. Thanks you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

I have just created a new project and in the .xml file will I change the constraints on the TextView (see orange circle).

To be "Match Constraint (Green circle)"

And then can I change the margin to move it longer away from the sides (Blue circle).

[image: Android studio .xml file]